# Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[32,128,768] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, out-of-memory

I have been getting this error after a few epochs. 
I have tried several suggestions found in similar questions such as

1. reduce the batch size of both training and test to 1
2. reduce the data size
3. use kill -9 pid
4. use more than one GPU by setting `os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '0,2'`
5. reduced the number of output neurons of the LSTM model
6. Adding `gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(allow_growth=True)
   session = tf.InteractiveSession(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))`
7. Adding `del model` after using the model
8. Adding `k.clear_session()`. I'm not sure I used this particular one correctly.

None of them work.

Does anyone have any other suggestions? Please help.
The tensor shape changes in different runs and different error message but the error message remains the same.

I'm using Python3.7, tensorflow-gpu==1.14, CuDNN=7.6.5, CUDA==10.0.

Comment: You have listed almost all the possible ways to fix the OOM issues through code. If any of those doesn't give desired result then the only option would be to increase the  hadware capacity. Like upgrading RAM and GPU.